# Does the standard library have a comparator reversal mechanism?

Tags: c++, templates, iterator, comparator, std

I know the standard library has [`std::reverse_iterator<...>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/reverse_iterator), which, given an iterator type, can be used to obtain its reverse (type).

Does it also have a similar mechanism for reversing comparators used for sorting/ordering? Something which takes a comparator type and produces the comparator corresponding to the reverse order (assuming the order is reversible)? e.g.
with `std::reverse_comparator<std::greater<int>>` being equivalent to `std::less<int>`?

Comment: `std::reverse_comparator<std::greater<int>>` should be `std::less_equal<int>`, shouldn't it?

Comment: @EdgarRokyan: No, I don't think so. Otherwise why have `std::less` rather than `std::less_equal` as the original comparator?

Comment: @einpoklum I concur with Edgar. If the purpose of your comparator reversal is blanket inversion, i.e. everything that was true is now false, and everything that was false is now true, then Edgar is exactly correct. `std::greater` is *strictly* greater. The inverse of that would everything *not* strictly-greater, which is everything less *or* equal.

Comment: @WhozCraig: See my edit. I'm interested in what you would use for sorting; perhaps that makes it clearer why I don't just want `return not original_comparator(x,y);`.

Comment: I assume you want to use the reverse comparator in a `map` or `set`-like context? In that case, you would really need `std::less` to be the “reverse” of `std::greater`, because maps and sets do not work correctly with a non-strict ordering.

Comment: @einpoklum I understand. To reverse the order you hope an inverted comparator will grant that. Though that makes high-level sense, Edgar's point (I think) was simply what I amplified. That being that inverting a comparator is not trivial when dealing with something that requires strict weak ordering. To your question, I don't think such a thing is provided by the std lib, though building one specific to your inversion needs would seem a fairly trivial task.

Comment: @mindriot: Exactly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C++17 introduces `std::not_fn` which will *"replace"* `std::greater<int>` by `std::less_equal<int>`.

which is not a correct comparer for `std::sort`/`std::map`.

Else in std, I don't think it exists one which *"transform"* into `std::less<int>`, but you can write your own easily, something like:

```
template <typename Comparer>
struct InvComparer
{
public:
    explicit InvComparer(Comparer comparer) : comp(comparer) {}
    template <typename T1, typename T2>
    bool operator() (const T1& lhs, const T2& rhs) const { return comp(rhs, lhs); };
private:
    Comparer comp;
};
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/YOzjZb)

Answer (score 1):

There is `not2`, which would generate the the binary complement of the input functor. However, the complement of `std::greater<T>` is not equivalent to `std::less<T>`, but `std::less_equal<T>` which is not a valid comparator for most standard algorithms. C++17 is going to introduce a generic `not_fn` that works with non-binary functors as well.

There is no out of the box solution for `std::less<T>` -> `std::greater<T>` but it should be possible to implement. Perhaps:

```
template<class Pred>
auto
fancy_not2(Pred&& pred) {
    return [pred=std::forward<Pred>(pred)](auto&& left, auto&& right){
        return left != right
            && !pred(std::forward<decltype(left)>(left),
                     std::forward<decltype(right)>(right));
    };
}
```

Comment: Note that `std::not2` is deprecated in C++17 (in favor to `std::not_fn`).

Comment: Yeah, there is no longer a need for it in the future. This fancy inverter doesn't translate to arbitrary arity though.